# Installing laravel on RHEL php54

Tags: php, laravel, rhel

So, RedHat Enterprise Linux doesn't support the MCrpyt module, but you can get it from the Fedora project through the EPL. This would work fine, except the fact that we're using SoftWare Collections (SCL) to get a newer version of PHP (5.4).

So what is the best approach to getting the dependencies for laravell on RHEL 6.6 and keeping PHP 5.4 in the most vendor supported way possible?

Comment: You tried php 5.4 from Remi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About mcrypt, **libmcrypt is a dead project**, unmaintained for ~8 years, last version 2.5.8 was released in February 2007!... and despite lot of open tickets, no activity. Cryptography is a very important part of security management. Looking at the past, and issue discovered / fixed in various software, and the need to always increase security standards, and to drop old algorithms, how can we imagine using an 8 years old software ?

More, http://blog.remirepo.net/post/2015/07/07/About-libmcrypt-and-php-mcrypt

This explain why php-mcript is not part of RHEL/RHSCL official packages.

Additional packages for php54 collection (including php54-php-mcrypt) are available on https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/remi/php54more/

And FYI, Laravel 5.1 doesn't requires mcrypt anymore.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: What is the problem with this answer ?  It contains explanation why mcrypt is not part of official RHSCL packages, and a alternatives repo to find it ?

Comment: Answers that consist mainly of links are considered as low quality answers on stackoverflow. The reason is that links die all the time and then the answer becomes invalid. Your answer has been put in to the low quality review queue by the system and, frankly speaking, I aggree with this choice. Instead of the first link, put more of the actual blog post into the answer and you should be fine.